# F-test: Testing unrestricted model vs. restricted model in Gretl and SPSS

Tags: multiple-regression, f-test, gretl

I have a proposed a model for Corporate Social Responsibility determinants (not important).
Among my independent variables I obtain two that are statistically not significant.
Following Wooldridge approach, in order to know if I should take out these two variables from the model, I should run a F-test, with the restricted and unrestricted model, right?

My question is: can I do this straighaway with a software like Gretl or SPSS? Or should I construct the statistic manually?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can perform an *F* test of two nested linear models, one of which estimates predictive parameters for your two variables, and the other of which restricts those parameters to zero (effectively excluding them) in SPSS? If so, you certainly can, and don't need to program such a test from scratch...

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Nick.
Yes indeed, I am asking about nested models, only instead of restricting to zero variables in the restricted model, I have 5 independent variables (vs. seven in the unrestricted model).
Could you roughly clarify how can I run this F-test in SPSS?
Thanks a lot, again.

Comment: Just to let everybody know, I found the way! I am still uncertain about SPSS, but Gretl has a very nice option menu once you have estimated a model. A new windows opens with the results and all the option bar is now applicable to the model, clicking around you will easily find the function to restrict the model excluding variables and performing the F-test straightaway. Nice feature in Gretl!

Comment: I think it would be good if this straightforward answer were actually posted as an "official" answer, otherwise this question looks unsolved in the listings. Not sure if you (Jose Antonio) are allowed to answer your own question here, though.